# Why does it only run every minute, why not at the specified 10-second interval?

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

Instead of the set 10-second repetition, it only runs every 1 minute.

```
private void setupSyncAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, SyncAlarmReceiver.class);

        syncPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

        long SYNC_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                SYNC_INTERVAL,
                syncPendingIntent
        );
    }
```

I want to achieve the 10 second interval, but only while the app is running or awake.

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of the set 10-second repetition, it only runs every 1 minute

Correct. There is a one-minute minimum threshold. Also, all repeating alarms are inexact.

> I want to reach the 10 second interval

That is not an option with `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How is it possible if AlarmManager is not capable of this

Comment: @ErikOrosz: Doing something every 10 seconds, 24 hours a day, is terrible for battery life. Users complained **very loudly** that they want better battery life.

Comment: I want it to work only when the application is in use. Necessary due to data changes.

Comment: @ErikOrosz: "I want it to work only when the application is in use" -- that is not what `AlarmManager` is for. Do something within your own application process, such as use `ScheduledExecutorService`.